# How to find the maximum product id in customer wise category in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

Here I have the customer id and max order quantity, how can I get the productid column for maximum orderquantity along with the customerid and maxorderqty column.

Database: adventure works
Tables used:salesorerheader,salesorderdetails

```sql
SELECT customerid,
       Max(totalqty)
FROM   (SELECT customerid,
               Sum(orderqty) AS Totalqty,
               productid     AS pdtid
        FROM   sales.salesorderheader a
               INNER JOIN sales.salesorderdetail b
                       ON a.salesorderid = b.salesorderid
        GROUP  BY customerid,
                  productid)A
WHERE  customerid = 29825
GROUP  BY customerid
```

Comment: Hi! Since you are new, I would like to invite you to give some more details about the database. It will help contributors if you could give a more complete overview about what your tables look like. It is always helpful to provide a minimal working example, so here it would be a good idea to give an example how your tables look when you fill them with a little data. Since you already provided a query that you tried, it would be helpful if you added what output the query currently produces and what you would expect it to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in finding single record, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) CustomerID, max(totalqty) AS maxqty, pdtid
FROM
(
  SELECT customerid, Sum(orderqty) AS Totalqty, productid AS pdtid
  FROM   sales.salesorderheader a
    INNER JOIN sales.salesorderdetail b
      ON a.salesorderid = b.salesorderid
  GROUP  BY customerid, productid
) A
WHERE CustomerID=29825
GROUP BY CustomerID, pdtid
ORDER BY max(totalqty) DESC
```

But... if you want to find several records with the same rank, use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY max(totalqty) DESC) rnk, CustomerID, max(totalqty) AS maxqty, pdtid
  FROM
  (
    SELECT customerid, Sum(orderqty) AS Totalqty, productid AS pdtid
    FROM   sales.salesorderheader a
      INNER JOIN sales.salesorderdetail b
        ON a.salesorderid = b.salesorderid
    GROUP  BY customerid, productid
  ) A
  WHERE CustomerID=29825
  GROUP BY CustomerID, pdtid
) B
WHERE rnk = 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=c6db129460a6198756d3e57086126572)

Another way is to 'join' sailes details again ;)

Comment: hey thanks man ,but all i wanted is corresponding product id for the maxorder, i already figuredout the maxqty for the customer but i want to include product id , if i select product i need to use group by which will bring different results , is there anything i can do about that.

Comment: Sorry, have you tried above queries? Seems, you don't. Take a looke here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=460d4f41481c351d8b5428e49faed202). The results are exactly the same as yours and contain `productid`.